# Possible Jerome Salinger short book about hockey player and his girlfriend

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm looking for a short book about hockey player and his girlfriend. I think it is by Jerome Salinger.

I've already read 50% of his books, which I can find on public. Only story about this crazy family of wonderkids and other little stories, and it's not that one, which I've read long-long time ago.

- Story was short. 1-2-3, may be 4 hours, not more, for an average person with average speed of reading.
- Probably, it was set in New York City. It may also be Chicago.
- Two main heroes - it is the hockey player and his girlfriend. He played, and something sad happened in the end.
- Timeframe of story: 1950-1990
- Timeframe of creation: 1950-1990

Possibly, it may not have been Jerome Salinger.

Comment: "*Story was short. 1-2-3, may be 4 hours.*" Do you mean the timespan in which the story was *set* (how long everything took within the story)? How about the length of the story itself: novel, just a few pages, something in between?

Comment: nope, I'm talking about average person and average time - required to read the story... I think it was lower than 100 pages, but off-course higher than 30 pages...